# Pass an array from ViewController to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have an array of floating point values called playbackRates, set in a ViewController. I want to use these values in a function within my appdelegate. How would I access these values from within my appdelegate?

ViewController.h

```
@interface P15ViewController : UIViewController <GuitarStringsViewDelegate>
{
    float playbackRates[6];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.guitarStringView.delegate = self;
    chordNameLabel.text = chordName;
    self.guitarStringView.chordName=chordName;

    if([chordName isEqualToString:@"A"]){
        playbackRates[0] = 1.0;
        playbackRates[1] = 1.0;
        playbackRates[2] = 2 * pow(2, (2/12));
        playbackRates[3] = 2 * pow(2, (2/12));
        playbackRates[4] = 2 * pow(2, (2/12));
        playbackRates[5] = 1.0;
    }
    else if([chordName isEqualToString:@"B"]){
    //set rates
    }
    else if([chordName isEqualToString:@"C"]){
    //set rates
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <PAEEngine/PAEEngine.h>
@interface P15AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

-(void)play:(int)index velocity:(float)velocity;

@end
```

appdelegate.m - player.rate needs to be set by each value in the array within the for loop in the play method

```
#import "P15AppDelegate.h"
#import "P15ViewController.h"

@interface P15AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) PAEAudioHost* host;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* channelStrips;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* filemnames;
@property (nonatomic) int nextVoice;
@end

@implementation P15AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.host = [PAEAudioHost audioHostWithNumOutputs:2];
    self.filemnames = @[@"guitar-E1.wav", @"guitar-A2.wav", @"guitar-D3.wav",
                        @"guitar-G3.wav", @"guitar-B3.wav", @"guitar-E4.wav"];
    const int numVoices = 8;

    NSMutableArray* channelStrips = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numVoices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVoices; ++i)
    {
        PAEChannelStrip* channelStrip = [PAEChannelStrip channelStripWithNumChannels:2];
        [channelStrips addObject:channelStrip];
    }

    self.channelStrips = [NSArray arrayWithArray:channelStrips];

    PAEAmplitude* amp = [PAEAmplitude amplitudeWithNumInputs:2];
    amp.input = [PAEMixer mixerWithSources:self.channelStrips];
    amp.level.input = [PAEConstant constantWithValue:1.0 / numVoices];

    self.host.mainMix = amp;

    [self.host start];

    return YES;
}

-(void)play:(int)index velocity:(float)velocity;
{

    if (index >= 0 && index < self.filemnames.count)
    {
        PAEAudioFilePlayer* player = [PAEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerNamed:self.filemnames[index]];
        player.loop = NO;
        player.rate - playbackRates[i]; --> **NEED TO ACCESS ARRAY HERE**

        PAEAmplitude* amp = [PAEAmplitude amplitudeWithNumInputs:player.numChannels];
        amp.input = player;
        amp.level.input = [PAEConstant constantWithValue:velocity];

        PAEChannelStrip* channelStrip = self.channelStrips[self.nextVoice];
        channelStrip.input = amp;

        self.nextVoice++;

        if (self.nextVoice == self.channelStrips.count)
            self.nextVoice = 0;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You can keep your array in the app delegate as property and then use that anywhere. But it is not good idea too. You should consider creating database or something like external file (plist) or NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to write a public accessor for the **playbackRates** array in your **UIViewController** subclass named **P15ViewController**.

P15ViewController.h add -

```
- (float)playbackRateAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

P15ViewController.m add -

```
- (float)playbackRateAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return playbackRates[index];
}
```

Your **appDelegate** needs to know of this method so import the **P15ViewController.h** in your **P15AppDelegate.m**, which I see you've already done.

Then assuming the **viewController** is the **rootViewController** of the **appDelegate** then you can access it with the following code.

Replace -

```
player.rate - playbackRates[i]; --> **NEED TO ACCESS ARRAY HERE**
```

With -

```
player.rate = [(P15ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController playbackRateAtIndex:i];
```

The typecast is needed so as to enable the calling of the accessor *(more specifically a getter)*.

If a more direct access way is needed then change the getter or add another getter to return the typed address of the **playbackRates** array like this in the P15ViewController.m -

```
- (float*)playbackRatesArray {
    return &playbackRates;
}
```

Remember to update the header file also!

And access it like this from P15AppDelegate.m, since a C array is just a pointer -

```
float* playbackRates = [(P15ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController playbackRatesArray];
player.rate = playbackRates[i];
```

Comment: Which ever way I try, I get an error message on the line that sets 'player.rate = ' saying "assignment to read only property" - any ideas?

Comment: That means you are trying to assign a value to a read-only property. In this case it's the rate property of PAEAudioFilePlayer class that most likely has been declared as read only.

Comment: How can I go about using the array to set this property then?